# S3 bucket image url not passing from backend to frontend. Suspect that async await is the issue

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, async-await, mern

Below is my code. What I don't understand is why `file.imageUrl` logs to the console fine on the backend but doesn't show up on the frontend. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with async await because if I change this:

```
const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
file.imageUrl = url;
```

to this:

```
//const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
file.imageUrl = 'test';
```

I then get `file.imageUrl` on the frontend.

---

**Backend:**

```
const getNoteById = async (req, res, next) => {
  const noteId = req.params.id;

  let note;
  try {
    note = await Note.findById(noteId);   
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError( `Something went wrong, could not find a note.`, 500 );
    return next(error);
  }  

  if (note.files.length) {
    note.files.forEach(async (file) => {
      const getObjectParams = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: file.name
      }
      const command = new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams);
      const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
      file.imageUrl = url;
      console.log('file.imageUrl:', file.imageUrl); // Logs the url correctly but doesn't come through in the response on the frontend.    
    })
  }

  if (!note) {
    const error = new HttpError( 'Could not find note for the provided id.', 404 );
    return next(error);
  }

  res.json({ note: note.toObject({ getters: true }) });
};
```

**Frontend:**

```
{loadedNote.files.length && (
  <div>
    {loadedNote.files.map(file => (
      <div key={file.name}>
        <span>file.name: {file.name}</span><br />
        <span>file.imageUrl: {file.imageUrl}</span>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: Use `for (const file of note.files) { ... }` instead of `note.files.forEach(...)` and retry.

Comment: @jarmod Holy crap that worked! I've been struggling with this for hours. What's the difference actually do?

Comment: [Using async/await in a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) doesn't do what most people think it does. Your `res.json(...)` code executes before the async/await code executes so the signed URLs are not yet populated when you return the response to the client.